# How to extract data from datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have difficulty in extracting data from datagrid. Since I was using selectionchange event on datagrid. I managed to get the selected row and column index. But I couldn't find any properties to get the exact data from the datagrid or datagridrow or selectedcells. Hope to get some advice from you guys, cheers.

Comment: Please be more specific - why  can't you use ItemsSource of your grid at the first place?

Comment: item source is a list, whose elements are contents for comboboxcolumn of datagrid. So I want to get the user's selected value.

Comment: I think one way is to get a "snapshot" of the datagrid when datagrid selectionchanged. But I couldn't find a property for it. Another way?(i'm not sure) is through binding. I want use textbinding the comboboxcolumn to a string and get the string when the selection changed. but i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Cast your grid's ItemsSource to a collection and get the item by index.

Comment: But can i know which one is selected?

Comment: didn't you say that you know selected row and index??

Comment: sorry i was not sure how collection works. i'm kinda a newbie for c# wpf.

Comment: I followed what you did now it basically works. but when I do a selection after I click some other area the selection gone(not exactly gone, since I click it back the selection appeared again). Is it some problem with textbinding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind your DataGrid to an ItemsSource containing your data, and then your SelectedItem will be the item in your ItemsSource.

You had a comment above of using ComboBoxes, so here's an example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" AutoGernateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ComboBoxOptions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                SelectedValueBinding="OptionId" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The DataContext for your DataGrid would contain

```
ObservableCollection<SomeItem> MyData { get; set; }
ObservableCollection<Option> ComboBoxOptions{ get; set; }
```

The `SomeItem` class would have a property of `OptionId`, and the `Option` class would have 
an `Id` and `Name` field.

In this example, when you select an item in the DataGrid the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` would contain the `SomeItem`

Remember, in WPF your Data (DataContext) is your application, and your UI elements like ComboBoxes, TextBoxes, DataGrids, etc are all just a pretty interface to let the user interact with your Data

Answer (score 0):

In your MouseDoubleClick Event , use the dataGrid1.SelectedIteam as Object.

The code should be like somewhat like following :

```
    private void dataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        edit(this.dataGrid1.SelectedItem as YourObject);
    }
```